# Discord Currency bot problem with for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, discord, discord.py

Here's the code

```py
@bot.command(aliases= ["inv"])
async def inventory(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    try:
        inventory = users[str(user.id)]["inventory"]
    except:
        inventory = []

    emb = discord.Embed(title=f"{user}'s Inventory", colour=discord.Colour.random())

    for item in inventory:
        amount = item["amount"]

    for thing in mainshop:
        title = thing["emojiname"]
        ali = thing["aliases"]

        emb.add_field(name=f"{title} - `{amount}`".title(), value=f"| `{ali}`", inline=False)

    await ctx.reply(embed = emb)
```

This is part of the `mainshop` for reference if it's needed.

```py
mainshop = [{"name":"Apple","price":2500,"description":"Red Apple","aliases":"apple","emoji":"<:Apple:9593214007677057>","emojiname":"Apple <:Apple:9593214003767057>"},
            {"name":"Fish","price":8500,"description":"Fish","aliases":"fish","emoji":"<:Salmon:959515944572948>","emojiname":"Fish <:Salmon:959351594457248>"},
```

Now I understand that the problem is the 2 "`for`"s but I literally have no idea how to fix it because I'm kinda new to this.
Here's what happens when I switch the `for` commands around.

**When mainshop is first**

[image: When mainshop is first]

**When inventory is first**

[image: When inventory is first]

What I want is the amount, name, alias and emoji all showing but it will only do one or the other..

If anyone could help me with this, I'd appreciate that alot, thanks

Comment: Hey Edioti, welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you be able to [edit] your post to include the *specific* problem you are facing with the `for` loops, as well as edit your code down to a [mcve]? This will help others better understand your question and assist you more effectively.

Comment: Hey, sorry I don't really know what I'm doing.. I'll try and add to it?